# C++ reference copying and assignment

Tags: c++

I have few questions regarding below code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
 A &  add(A & b);
};

A &  A::add(A & z)
{
    A * a = new A();
    A & b = *a;
    cout << "Inside add, address of a: " << &a << endl;
    cout << "Inside add, address of b: " << &b << endl;
    cout << "Inside add, address of z: " << &z << endl;
    A aa;
    cout << "Inside, add, address of aa: " << &aa << endl;
    return aa;
}


int main()
{

    A *a = new A();
    cout << "Original a: " << a << endl;
    A & b = a->add(*a);
    cout << "b: " << &b <<  endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Q1. Inside main, line 3, `a->add(*a)`, the same object pointed by pointer *a is passed. But inside the function `A::add(A &)`, when i try to achieve the same effect via `A &b = *a`, i get a different object. Why is this so?

Q2. Inside `A::add(A &)`, i return a non const reference to a local object `aa` and main gets the same memory address as the local reference. So this has the effect of extending the lifetime of local reference, beyond its scope.

Q3. Inside `A::add(A &)`, i dereference `*a` multiple times, first via `A &b = *a` and then by `return *a`. In both cases, the memory address is always the same. How is this happening? You can check the output of `&b` inside `A::add(A &)`and the result of `A &b = a->add(*a)`

UPDATE:

1. The issue related to Q1 was that i was doing `cout << &a`, when i should have been doing `cout << a`
2. To eliminate return value optimization, i compiled with -fno-elide-constructors. I am using g++.

Answer (score 2):

**A1:** You created a new *a with `A* a = new A()` The `a` in main is different than the `a` in `A::add`. The `a` in main is referenced by the variable `z`

**A2:** No, you created `a` on the heap, so it is going to last until you call `delete` on that variable

**A3:** A dereference does not change the memory location that is stored in the pointer, it just gets the value stored in that location. A reference is more like an alias. So `&b` is like saying `&(*a)`

Comment: for Q1, i understand that a in main() is different object than a in function add(). My question is that if i pass a reference to a function, the correct object gets passed, but within a function, if i try to create a reference to an existing object, i am getting a different object and consequently, within function add(), the memory address of a and b are different

Comment: For Q2, i changed the code to show that an object on function stack is being returned. As you can see from the memory address, the object on stack lives beyond the function.

Comment: Your change for Q2 is undefined behavior now. It _may_ work in some scenarios but it by no means is guaranteed